# Javascript don't recognises jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a dialogue with buttons in html, and I'm using jQuery to hide the old lines and show the new ones. In this way, when you click on a button, yoa can continue "talking". I started it in JSfiddle, and it worked perfectly. But now, I want to put it on a real site, and jquery doesn't do anything. Here I have the fiddle, which actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/MeisterAbababa/xHk5g/207/. 
I think I'm doing something wrong with the html or using the ID's not correctly, but I don´t what to do.

Edit:
Those are the errors in the browser's console:

SyntaxError: syntax error jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1

ReferenceError: $ is not defined Apple.js:2

(I might have made a stupid mistake).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  <html> <head> <title>Talking to Universe</title> <link href="Apples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" > <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="Apple.js"></script>

</head> <body> <div ID="PT1" class="presentationtext">Good morning.
    <button Id="PR1">Hello</button> </div> <div ID="PT2" class="presentationtext">I'm the Universe. Nice to meet you.
    <button Id="PR2">The pleasure is mine</button> </div> <div ID="PT3" class="presentationtext">I'm boring here. Why you don´t get this coin?
    <button Id="PR3">Get the coin</button> </div> <div ID="PT4" class="presentationtext">Oh. You can buy things. We are in space, so you can buy almost everything. Let´s start buying an apple farm and an Apple Button.
    <button Id="PR4">Get the things you have said with the coin you gave me.</button> 

</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also her's the script:

```
   //Menu  $("#TableClicker").css();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PR1").click(function () {
        $("#PT2").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#PT1").hide();
    });
    $("#PR2").click(function () {
        $("#PT3").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#PT2").hide();
    });
    $("#PR3").click(function () {
        $("#PT4").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#PT3").hide();
    });
    $("#PR4").click(function () {
        $("#MenuButton").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#AppleFarmButton").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#TableClicker").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#PT4").hide();
    });
    $("#MenuButton").click(function () {
        $("#TableClicker").hide();
    });
    $("#AppleFarmButton").click(function () {
        $("#TableClicker").show();
    });
});
```

And here is the css:

```
/*Presentation*/
.presentationtext{
}
#PT1{
    visibility:visible;
}
#PT2{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#PT3{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#PT4{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: -1 for bad question title, please write an informative title for your question.

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your actual web page?  What errors are being reported in the browser error console or debugger console?  Are you sure your scripts are being loaded properly?

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the errors. Yes, the link to jquery's script in the head of the html.

Comment: Check in 'Net' on your console and see if jquery has loaded.  If not, check the link - or try loading from a CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that jQuery is not successfully loading in your page.

The most likely reason for this is that `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` is not properly located in the same directory on your server as your HTML page and thus the browser doesn't find it when you specify this `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that was. Thanks.

Comment: @MeisterAbababa - Anytime something isn't working as I'm expecting, the very first thing I do is check the browser debug console for errors.  It often contains a clue as to what is causing the issue.